# Windows gives error "Unable to save display settings" when all 4 monitor ports are used

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have 4 monitors: (2) 1920 x 1080 monitors and (2) 1600 x 900 monitors hooked up as follows:

- 1920x1080 -> HDMI 2.0
- 1920x1080 -> DVI-D
- 1600x900 -> DisplayPort to DVI.
- 1600x900 -> DVI-D

I can have any 3 on at the same time which I please, but activating a fourth monitor results in "The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings."

I'm using an R9 390X and Windows 10.1.

How and I work around this to let me use all monitors at full resolution and refresh rate?

Comment: It may help if you edit your question to elaborate regarding your hardware:  which video cards do you have installed, which driver software versions for those video cards, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it can be challenging to get four (or even three) monitors to play nice with one another unless the video cards are the same make/model.  Of course that isn't always the case, but it definitely seems to make life much easier.

That being said, is it possible that one of those video cards is essentially an either/or situation?  In other words, some video cards have a Display Port output next to a DVI output, but they are actually there to provide you with a choice between the two connection types and they can't both function simultaneously.

Comment: strange. In this one I have seen that any of the three monitors can function at the same time

Comment: Hopefully, someone else will be able to chime in who has some experience configuring an R9 390X.  From what I have read, others have occasionally encountered the same problem.